# Azure DevOps giving "Page cannot be reached" error

Tags: azure-devops

I have been trying to login into azure but I keep getting a "This page can't be reached" error. Same thing when I go to other Microsoft Accounts. Anyone else facing this issue or it's just me?

Answer (score 0):

Please check with the following things:

1. Try the login to Azure DevOps on different machines, and with different networks.
2. You also can check if you are able to access the web sites of other services, such as GitHub, Bitbucket, etc..
3. If you are able to access the services on some other machines or networks but not on your machine, go to check whether there is any restriction for IP addresses and domain URLs has been set in the firewall or proxy server on the machine. If yes, you need to add the IP addresses and domain URLs of Azure service to the **Allow list**. For more details, you can see "[**Allowed address lists and network connections**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/allow-list-ip-url?view=azure-devops)".

Comment: Even the link you have provided to see how to allow IP addresses is giving an error. But let me try what you have suggested.

Comment: It has started working on it's own. Didn't do anything.

Comment: Hi @SmithWalikoMsiska, glad that the problem has gone on your side. To avoid the problem occurs again, as the document mentioned, you can try to add the URLs of Azure DevOps and Azure into the allow-list of the firewall on your machine. Feel free to tell contact us, if the problem occurs again, or if you have any question about this.

Comment: that's odd. I can access stackoverflow but can't access azure devops